# WCF from VBA Security

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have created a WCF service that is hosted as a windows service. I am using a Moniker to call the service from VBA in my excel documents.

The service is using the netTcp binding protocol. What I want to do is find out how I can validate the user based on a user group or by their AD account.

I have tried putting the following code in the UpdateFile which is being called from VBA but it returns the name of the user account on the machine where the service is running.

```
  ServiceSecurityContext serviceSecurityContext = ServiceSecurityContext.Current;
  if (serviceSecurityContext != null)
  {
    string accountText = serviceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;
  }
```

I need to make sure only authenticated users call to the Windows Service is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The following article shows how to do this from a web hosted wcf service but it shouldn't make any difference if you are using netTcp:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx#Step3

Comment: It does not seem to specify how to do this from a service hosted WCF service.